# zum Lächeln vs. um zu lächeln

Tags: noun, verb-usage

Diese Frage betrifft den folgenden Satz aus *Kindergeschichten* von Peter Bichsel.

> Ich will von einem alten Mann erzählen, von einem Mann, der kein Wort mehr sagt, ein müdes Gesicht hat, zu müd **zum Lächeln** und zu müd, **um böse zu sein**.

**FRAGE**

1. Bedeutet *zum Lächeln* das gleiche wie *um zu lächeln*?
2. Wenn nein zu 1, wie unterscheidet sich *zum Lächeln* von *um zu lächeln*?
3. Wenn ja zu 1, kann man *zum Lächeln* als Vorlage bei irgendein Verb verwenden?  Kann man zum Beispiel *zum böse Sein* sagen?  Falls nein, auf welche Art ist die Verwendung eingeschränkt?

**HINTERGRUND**

Diese ist meine erste Frage in deutsch und eigentlich der erste Versuch der Komposition in deutsch. Korrigieren Sie sie wo immer sie sich bessern kann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zu Frage 1: In diesem Zusammenhang meint beides dasselbe. Das gilt aber nicht immer. zum Beispiel: Es ist nicht einfach, ihn zum Lächeln zu bringen. / Es ist nicht einfach, ihn dazu zu bringen zu lächeln.

Zu Frage 2: das Lächeln ist in diesem Fall ein substantiviertes Verb. Es kann in dieser Weise in jeder Formulierung mit der Präposition "zu" zu "zum Lächeln" werden. "um zu lächeln" ist eine Formulierung, die eine Absicht, ein Ziel oder - wie im Beispiel - eine Fähigkeit ausdrückt.

Zu Frage 3: Man kann es als Vorlage verwenden. Grammatikalisch geht das immer, allerdings mit stilistisch unterschiedlichen Qualitäten. Bei Formulierungen, in denen das Verb ein Adverb hat, ist die Substantivierung nicht zu empfehlen und möglicherweise sogar falsch (z.B schön schreiben, laut lachen, böse sein etc.).

Comment: Ist das auch korrekt: "zum Bösesein"?

Answer (score 2):

1. Ja, das bedeutet dasselbe.
2. -
3. Das was hier passiert, nennt man *Substantivierung*.

Bei einer Substantivierung wird ein Verb oder ein Adjektiv so verwendet, wie ein Substantiv. Meinst erkennt man das an einem vorangestellten Artikel, wie er in »zum« ja vorhanden ist (»zum« = »zu dem«; »dem« ist ein Artikel).

Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, aber ich glaube, das kann man mit jedem Verb machen:

> Das **Gehen** fällt der alten Dame schon schwer.

Mit »zu« findet man das schon seltener, aber auch das ist nichts ungewöhnliches:

> Das ist so traurig, es ist zum **Weinen**.
>   *(Achtung, der folgende Satz ist eine sehr deftige Beschimpfung):* Bu bist doch zum **Scheißen** zu blöd!

Aber gerade bei dem von dir genannten Beispiel wäre ich vorsichtig. Grammatisch ist es zwar in Ordnung, zwischen einen Artikel und ein substantiviertes Verb noch ein attributives Adjektiv zu stellen, aber stilistisch ist das eher nicht die beste Wahl.

Nachdem es aber kaum sinnvoll ist, »sein« ohne ein Attribut zu substantivieren, würde ich dazu raten, die Konstruktion

> zum + <*Attribut*> + Sein

eher nicht zu verwenden.

Aber ohne »zu« ist das durchaus möglich:

> Das Fotomodel hielt **das schön Sein** eine Zeit lang für eine ausreichende Lebensgrundlage.

Comment: Thank you. I want to note that I find this answer as helpful as the one I "chose." When this happens, I give the "choice" to the answer from the member with lower reputation score so as to encourage participation.